# Polars equivalent of pandas factorize

Tags: python-polars

Does polars have the function to encode string column into integers (1, 2, 3) like [pandas.factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)?

Didn't find it in the polars documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for a [dense rank](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rank.html#polars.Expr.rank) or the [categorical type.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/performance/strings.html#categorical-type)

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"column": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "foo"]})
df.with_columns(rank = pl.col("column").rank("dense"))
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌────────┬──────┐
│ column | rank │
│ ---    | ---  │
│ str    | u32  │
╞════════╪══════╡
│ foo    | 3    │
│ bar    | 1    │
│ baz    | 2    │
│ foo    | 3    │
│ foo    | 3    │
└────────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

A common purpose of `pd.factorize` is to return a series' set of unique values as well as the indices of those unique values in the original series.

The following approach works with any datatype. I am using integers because it is easy to generate a high number that will also include duplicates.

Lets start with the following pandas example:

```py
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)

codes, uniques = pd.factorize(arr)
```

Here `uniques` contains a list of the unique values in arr. `codes` contains the indices of those unique values in the original array. We can reconstruct the original `arr` from these by using numpy's "[advanced integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)":

```py
np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr, uniques[codes]) # no error
```

We can reproduce this by finding the unique values of our series, adding a row index and doing a left join onto our original series:

```py
def factorize(series: pl.Series) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    name = series.name
    df = series.to_frame()
    df_ranked = df.unique(maintain_order=True).with_row_index(name=f"{name}_index")
    uniques = df_ranked[name].to_numpy()
    codes = df.join(df_ranked, how="left", on=name)[f"{name}_index"].to_numpy()
    return codes, uniques

df_polars = pl.DataFrame({"foo": arr})
pl_codes, pl_uniques = factorize(df_polars["foo"])

# test that we can reproduce the original array
np.testing.assert_array_equal(pl_uniques[pl_codes], arr)

# test that the values match pandas output (and sorting)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(pl_uniques, uniques)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(pl_codes, codes)
```