# How to encode a string column into integers on polars?

Tags: python-polars

I would like to "encode" in a simple manner the values of a given column, a string for instance, into an arbitrary integer identifier?

```
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({"animal": ['elephant', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'],
    "country": ['Mexico', 'Denmark', 'Mexico', 'France'], 
    "cost": [1000.0, 20.0, 10.0, 120.0]})
)
print(df)
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ animal   ┆ country ┆ cost   │
│ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ str      ┆ str     ┆ f64    │
╞══════════╪═════════╪════════╡
│ elephant ┆ Mexico  ┆ 1000.0 │
│ dog      ┆ Denmark ┆ 20.0   │
│ cat      ┆ Mexico  ┆ 10.0   │
│ mouse    ┆ France  ┆ 120.0  │
└──────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

I would like to encode the `animal` and the `country` columns to get something like

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌──────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ animal   ┆ country ┆ cost   ┆ animal_encoded ┆ country_encoded │
│ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---             │
│ str      ┆ str     ┆ f64    ┆ i64            ┆ i64             │
╞══════════╪═════════╪════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ elephant ┆ Mexico  ┆ 1000.0 ┆ 0              ┆ 0               │
│ dog      ┆ Denmark ┆ 20.0   ┆ 1              ┆ 1               │
│ cat      ┆ Mexico  ┆ 10.0   ┆ 2              ┆ 0               │
│ mouse    ┆ France  ┆ 120.0  ┆ 3              ┆ 2               │
└──────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I thought that doing some sort of row indexing from a `unique`d context and then `over` to expand to the same number of original rows could work out but I can't manage to implement it.

Comment: Should `country_encoded` not be `[0, 1, 0, 2]`, `Mexico` having the same number? e.g. `df.with_columns(pl.col('animal', 'country').cast(pl.Categorical).to_physical().suffix('_encoded'))`

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. By the way, thanks to another answer of yours I managed to solve it the question. So thanks for that too.

Comment: Ah okay. You can pass multiple names to `.col()` instead of a list-comp if you prefer. e.g. `pl.col('animal', 'country').rank().cast().suffix()`

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a solution, based on the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75555521/polars-equivalent-of-pandas-factorize).

```
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({
    "animal": ['elephant', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'], 
    "country": ['Mexico', 'Denmark', 'Mexico', 'France'], 
    "cost": [1000.0, 20.0, 10.0, 120.0]})
)

(
     df
    .with_columns([
    pl.col(i).rank('dense').cast(pl.Int64).suffix('_encoded') for i in ['animal', 'country']
    ])

)

shape: (4, 5)
┌──────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ animal   ┆ country ┆ cost   ┆ animal_encoded ┆ country_encoded │
│ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---             │
│ str      ┆ str     ┆ f64    ┆ i64            ┆ i64             │
╞══════════╪═════════╪════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ elephant ┆ Mexico  ┆ 1000.0 ┆ 3              ┆ 3               │
│ dog      ┆ Denmark ┆ 20.0   ┆ 2              ┆ 1               │
│ cat      ┆ Mexico  ┆ 10.0   ┆ 1              ┆ 3               │
│ mouse    ┆ France  ┆ 120.0  ┆ 4              ┆ 2               │
└──────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Comment: It's important to add  `.rank(dense)` otherwise it will just keep ranking without giving the same encoding for previously seen elements.